# UITableController in UINavigationController back to previous view / controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I have setup my app such that a UINavigationController manages a MKMapView followed by an UITableViewController.
Now, I want to handle selections in the table such that once selected, the focus will go back to the mapview immediately, without having click on the standard back button on top.
Should I add a segue here or what is the Apple way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This line of code causes the navigationController to navigate "back" to the previous view controller.